# Capturing optional groups regex expressions Php

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I almost have the full regex expression, but, there is a case that i'm not able to match.

I need to capture: The xxxx word if exist, the decimals (30), and the 'cm'.

I have expressions like:

30x30cm

30 x 30 cm

30x30 cm

xxxx 30x30cm

xxxx (30x30cm) -> That case does not match the word xxxx (if exist I need to capture)

xxxx (30 x 30 cm)->That case does not match the word xxxx (If exist I need to capture)

Thats my regex nowadays:

```
(?:(\w+))?\s?\b(\d+)\s?x\s?(\d+)\s?(cm)\b
```

How I can match with the word xxxx if exist? Any help would be appreciated

[https://regex101.com/r/morihH/1][1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may add optional whitespaces and a `(` to the first optional non-capturing group:

```
(?:(\w+)\s*\(?)?\b(\d+)\s?x\s?(\d+)\s?(cm)\b
        ^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OFZEXm/1) (`\s` replaced with a space since the input string is a multiline one).

The `\s*\(?` match 0+ whitespaces followed with an optional `(`.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor. Works like a charm. Regards

Comment: And if i want to match 30.13 x 30,12 cm? The measures with decimals?

Comment: @Albeis: Since you are *extracting* values, I would replace `\d+` with `\d[\d.,]*` (a digit followed with 0+ digits, dots or commas). See [this regex demo update](https://regex101.com/r/OFZEXm/2).

Comment: Thanks again. I was trying by doing the decimal optional, but i was capturing the entire part and the decimal part splitted. Better your way!:)